# wherein condition in laravel Auth::attempt

Tags: laravel

```
$usernameinput = Input::get('email');
            $password = Input::get('password');
            $field = filter_var($usernameinput, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';

            if (Auth::attempt(array($field => $usernameinput, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1), true)) {
    //success
    }else{
    //error
}
```

I am trying to login those user who has username/email active and user type either 1,2,3,4 how can i set wherein type = [1,2,3,4]; in attempt laravel

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code may be help to you

```
$user=User::where('email','=',$usernameinput)->first()




if (Auth::attempt(array($field => $usernameinput, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1,'type'=>in_array($user->type,[1,2,3,4])), true)) {
//success
}else{
//error
```

Comment: this should also check if username is avail this will generate $user null if i input username

Comment: Yes you can check that user exist or not